# Passing a props to call a function is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I have a Cancel button. I would like to perform a specific function in another js file when the button is pressed. Here is what I am doing.

```
function Add(props) {
  const [cancel, setCancel] = useState(false);

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setCancel(true);
    <UploadFile cancel={cancel}/>
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
         <DialogActions>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</Button>
         </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In another file UploadFile.js, the code as below:

```
const UploadFile = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.cancel) {
            remove();
        }
    },);

    const remove = () => {
    //Doing removing files
    ...
    };
}
```

But the remove() is never called. I am not sure useEffect() is properly used.

Comment: Inside UploadFile, there are many functions and UI components (button, progress bar...). In this case, I don't want to reder Upload component again, what I intend to do is only call remove() function when Cancel button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the remove function inside useEffect, which only renders once when the page loads. This means the remove function would only be called when UploadFile renders. Try moving the if statement out of useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass cancel prop as denpendency in useEffect to trigger update this useEffect.

```
const UploadFile = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.cancel) {
            remove();
        }
    }, [props.cancel]);

    const remove = () => {
    //Doing removing files
    ...
    };
}
```

Note: Do not put component inside handle logic functions